# How to diff two files with same number of lines, and get only different lines

Tags: command-line, diff

Given 2 files which have the same number of lines, is it possible the get a diff with **ONLY** change (`c`), in other words, **WITHOUT** additions (`a`) and deletions (`d`)?

For example, here are 2 files with 10 lines each.

> file1.txt:

```
apple
apple
pear
grape
pear
grape
pear
pear
pear
apple
```

> file2.txt:

```
apple
apple
pear
pear
pear
pear
pear
pear
pear
apple
```

Calling `diff file1.txt file2.txt` would produce:

```
4d3
< grape
6c5,6
< grape
---
> pear
> pear
```

Is it possible to get a result like:

```
4c4
< grape
---
> pear
6c6
< grape
---
> pear
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
diff <(nl file1.txt) <(nl file2.txt) | awk '{$2=""; print}' | sed -e 's/^\([<>]\)  /\1 /'
```

The `nl` command numbers the lines, which makes it possible to use `diff` [line-by-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136380/compare-two-files-strictly-line-by-line-without-insertions-or-deletions). The `awk` command selects everything in the `diff` output except for the line numbers added by `nl`. In other words, it removes the line numbers. The `sed` command removes an awkward extra space that `awk` leaves behind.